# How to get WooCommerce Product Category Link by ID?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, link-category

WooCommerce's product categories are a custom taxonomy called `product_cat`. In a function I'm writing, I'm using `get_categories` with the `taxonomy` parameter set to `product_cat`. Everything works fine and I can get the term id, the name, and even the slug. What I can't figure out is how to get the link to display. Apparently `get_category_link` doesn't work with custom taxonomy and `get_term_link` isn't working either, I get an error. Here's what I have:

```
$prod_cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'empty'        => 0
);

$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );

foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
    $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
    $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name

    $return .= '<a href="' . get_category_link( $woo_cat_id ) . '">' . $woo_cat_name . '</a>';
}//end of $woo_categories foreach
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another update (Sept. 2015):

I *can* use `get_term_link` after all. The problem was that the string needed to be converted to an integer. Used a [Stack Overflow tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008214/php-string-to-int) for the fastest way to convert it using the (int)$value in PHP.

So it would look like this if you don't want to use the slug in the foreach loop:

```
$woo_cat_id_int = (int)$woo_cat_id; //convert
```

That converted value is used instead of the slug in `get_term_link`. Hope it helps someone. :-)

---

Looks like I figured it out.

I used [get_term_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link). And I was getting an error because I was using it this way:

```
get_term_link( $woo_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Which gave me this error:

> Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

So I went this route instead with the `slug` and it worked:

```
$prod_cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'empty'        => 0
);

$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );

foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
    $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
    $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
    $woo_cat_slug = $woo_cat->slug; //category slug


    $return .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $woo_cat_slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $woo_cat_name . '</a>';
}//end of $woo_categories foreach
```

Comment: Although I still don't understand why it won't take the ID but it takes the slug. The Codex says get_term_link should take the ID...

Comment: Makes zero sense - should work with the id indeed... many thanks

Comment: Term_id is a string on the object. To use it with the get term link function you need to parse it as an integer first `get_term_link( intval($woo_cat->term_id), 'product_cat' )`

Comment: The solution by forsvunnet woked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I use

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );
 echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prod_cat_args = array(
'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'empty'        => 0
            );

            $terms = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
            //$term_id=6;
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
            echo '<li><a class="shopping-now" href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            }
```

[`get_term_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) does work smoothly, when using the object returned by `get_categories()`.

Answer (score 0):

I try this code and it works.

```
<?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '17,77')); ?>

<?php foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : 
       $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id,'thumbnail_id', true );
       $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
       $wcategory =$term_link = get_term_link( $catTerm );
?>
<ul>
    <li><a class="tr" href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"><?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>"><?php endif;?><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```